# Preventing C# crashing with invalid user input

Tags: c#, crash

brand new to coding C#, ~2 weeks into learning the language. I've had an idea for a mobile game rattling around in my head for over a year now and one of my resolutions was to learn to code this year. I'm working my way through an intro to C# book and having gotten the basics down I'm toying with coding an old school text based adventure as a skills reinforcer. I guess this is a 3 part question 1) I'm trying to code a system where the user chooses a value between 1-10 for attribute types but can't figure out how to stop the program from crashing if the user enters something other than an int. 2) I'm trying to code a way that the game will subtract from the original attribute value the values of attributes already assigned to ensure the user can't end up with more than 25. 3) I want to include a code at the bottom that allows the user to start over if they don't like the setup. Below is my code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Now you must choose your basic attributes!. You have a total of 25 points to distribute over 5 core skills:");
        Console.WriteLine("Strength, Speed, Intelligence, Personality, and Ingenuity.");
        Console.WriteLine("Choose carefully! Values too high or too low may impact your ability to escape from the world!");
        int attributes = 25;
        int strength = -1;
        int speed = -1;
        int intelligence = -1;
        int personality = -1;
        int ingenuity = -1;
        Console.WriteLine("Attributes remaining: " + (attributes));
        do
        {

            Console.Write("Please choose a value for Strength (0-10): ");
            string strengthAsText = Console.ReadLine();
            strength = Convert.ToInt32(strengthAsText);
            if(strength > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You can't be that fast!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good choice, please choose the next attribute.");
                attributes = 25 - strength;
                Console.WriteLine("Attributes remaining: " + (attributes));
            }
       }
        while (strength < 0 || strength > 10 && strength <= attributes);

        int attributes2 = (attributes - strength);
        do
        {

            Console.Write("Please choose a value for Speed (0-10): ");
            string speedAsText = Console.ReadLine();
            speed = Convert.ToInt32(speedAsText);
            if (speed > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You can't be that fast!");
            }
            else if (speed < attributes2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You do not have enough remaining attributes to be this fast. Please choose again.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good choice, please choose the next attribute.");
                attributes2 = (attributes2 - speed);
                Console.WriteLine("Attributes remaining: " + (attributes2));
            }
        }
        while (speed < 0 || speed > 10 && speed <= attributes2);

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please choose a value for Intelligence (0-10): ");
            string intelligenceAsText = Console.ReadLine();
            intelligence = Convert.ToInt32(intelligenceAsText);
            if (intelligence > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You can't be that smart!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good choice, please choose the next attribute.");
                Console.WriteLine("Attributes remaining: " + (attributes - strength - speed - intelligence));
            }
        }
        while (intelligence < 0 || intelligence > 10 && intelligence <= attributes);

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please choose a value for Personality (0-10): ");
            string personalityAsText = Console.ReadLine();
            personality = Convert.ToInt32(personalityAsText);
            if (personality > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You can't be that charismatic!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good choice, please choose the next attribute.");
                Console.WriteLine("Attributes remaining: " + (attributes - strength - speed - intelligence - personality));
            }
        }
        while (personality < 0 || personality > 10 && personality <= attributes);

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please choose a value for Ingenuity (0-10): ");
            string ingenuityAsText = Console.ReadLine();
            ingenuity = Convert.ToInt32(ingenuityAsText);
            if (ingenuity > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You can't be that creative!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good choice, please choose the next attribute.");
                Console.WriteLine("Attributes remaining: " + (attributes - strength - speed - intelligence - personality - ingenuity));
            }
        }
        while (ingenuity < 0 || ingenuity > 10 && ingenuity <= attributes);

        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, you have chosen wisely.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Your final attribute values are: ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Strength     " + (strength));
        Console.WriteLine("Speed        " + (speed));
        Console.WriteLine("Intelligence " + (intelligence));
        Console.WriteLine("Personaility " + (personality));
        Console.WriteLine("Ingenuity    " + (ingenuity));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to continue...");

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("You begin you journey by awakening in a pile of what looks like starship debris.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

I apologize if this is messy, like I said I'm as new to this as it gets. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To stop your program crashing when the value is other than an int use the TryParse method:

   ```
   bool result = Int32.TryParse(value,out number) //value is the input, number is the output
   If (result)
   {
       //value converted successfully 
   }
   else
   {
       //value failed to convert
   }
   ```
2. No need to create a second variable attributes2. Just need to use the first one and keep decrementing it. This will ensure that you can keep track of a total of 25 attributes.
3. Wrap your routine in a method and call it again if the user wants to start over like this:

   ```
   string s = Console.ReadLine();
   If (s == "start over")
   {
       StartOver(); //this method contains your whole routine
   }
   else
   {
       //exit the application or whatever you want done here
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you Vivek! First chance I've had to correctly use a method and it worked perfectly.